# How to persist tenant id in Vue Router

Tags: vue-router

I want in my application most URLs to start with `tenantId` (e.g. https://example.com/tenantId/some/page).

So I have configured Vue router so almost each rout path starts with parameter `/:tenantId/...`. But now I'm facing an issue that in each and every router-link I have to pass the value of this tenantId that leads to a lot of boiler plate.

I would like to make value of this parameter persistent, so if current page has tenantId value - navigation target will use it or if current page has no tenantId then it should use a user default one. And all this until tenantId value is explicitly set in a location object.

Is there is a simple way to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

Lets see if I understand correctly...

With Vue-router you can have:
route: /page/:tenantId and a route /page right underneath.

Each of these can go to a diferente view or component

if the route has tenantId it will go to the first if not it will go to the second
You will have to implement in the second route what to do until you get the tenantId

```
        {
          path: '/page/:tenantId',
          name: 'With',
          props: true,
          component: () => import('./views/Tenant.vue')
        },
        {
          path: '/page',
          name: 'Without',
          component: () => import('./views/NoTenant.vue')
        },
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This part works fine. I was asking about avoiding to pass tenantId explicitly in each `router-link` or `router.push()`. So instead of passing `{ name: "orders", params: { tenantId: "eu" } }` I would like to just pass "orders" and have correct `tenantId` persisted from current page (or falback to user settings).